# Magento 1.9 custom category list left bar

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento 1.9 installation with a left bar in catalog pages that show main categories with an accordion with all subcategories.

I want, for a specific category and its subcategories to customize this left menu to show only this and not all categories.

Example Normal menu:

- Category 1
- Category 2

  - Sub Category 2_1
  - Sub Category 2_2
- Category 3

  - Sub Category 3_1
  - Sub Category 3_2
- Category 4

What I want to do when only I'm in Category 3 or its subcategories

- Category 3

  - Sub Category 3_1
  - Sub Category 3_2

How to realize this?

Comment: What theme are you using? Not a standard magento one right?

Comment: Yes, custom theme. Granada theme.